# Visual Micro compiled code won't run on Arduino, same code runs when compiled by Arduino IDE

Tags: visual-studio, arduino

I'm nearing the memory limit of an Arduino with the code I've written. When uploaded via Visual Micro extension for Visual Studio, the Arduino is non-responsive after a restart. However, the exact same code runs fine when uploaded via Arduino IDE.

I've disabled Visual Micro debugging, as I know that adds extra memory usage.  Is there anything else that can be disabled to free up memory?

Comment: Probably a simple fix, however all we'll be able to do is guess. Could probably do more with more details of the compiled difference. Have you tested visual micro runs any code properly, etc...